# Pulling out a specific word or phrase from sql table

Tags: sql

So I'm writing a report that pulls all versions of adobe acrobat pro into a single sql report. The problem I'm coming across is that Adobe changes its naming convention from version to version. Some display 'Adobe Acrobat 7.1.0 Professional' while others display 'Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro'. My question is I can display the version in another column, but is it possible to only display 'Adobe Acrobat Pro' for all of the different versions and parse out the the #?

Also please forgive me, I'm still newish to the whole sql query thing. But I've done a lot of digging and cant seem to find anything that'll work for me.

Thanks in advance

Scott

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.DisplayName0 AS [Display Name], LEFT(v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.Version0, 1) AS Version, 
                      v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.Publisher0 AS Publisher, v_R_System_5.User_Name0 AS [User Name], 
                      v_R_System_5.Name0 AS [Computer Name], DATEDIFF(day, v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS_5.LastHWScan, GETDATE()) AS [Last Scan]
FROM         v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS AS v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5 INNER JOIN
                      v_R_System AS v_R_System_5 ON v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.ResourceID = v_R_System_5.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                      v_R_System_Valid AS v_R_System_Valid_5 ON v_R_System_5.ResourceID = v_R_System_Valid_5.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                      v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS AS v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS_5 ON 
                      v_R_System_5.ResourceID = v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS_5.ResourceID
WHERE     (v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.Publisher0 LIKE '%Adobe%') AND (v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.Version0 LIKE '7%') AND 
                      (v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Acrobat%Pro%') AND 
                      (NOT (v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_5.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Distiller%'))
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect (e.g. SQL Server 2008R2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with SQL -- depending on your dialect and permissions possibly by writing a user defined function or through another language (e.g. CLR assemblies on SQL Server via C# / VB.NET). I'm not sure what your use case is, however in some of my SQL string-manipulation cases writing it in a compiled (or JIT compiled) language ended in largely improved performance -- **However** it varies on a case-by-case basis, and it's easier to get started using SQL-only solutions:

Here's a quick version I threw together in SQL Server 2008R2 (although it should work in 2005):

```
create function dbo.fFuncName ( @in varchar(128) )
returns varchar(128)
as begin
    declare @out varchar(128)
    declare @i int
    declare @c char
    declare @len int
    declare @lastWasSpace bit
    set @out = ''
    set @i = 1
    set @len = len(@in)
    set @lastWasSpace = 1
    while @i <= @len begin
        set @c = substring(@in, @i, 1)
        set @i = @i + 1
        if @c >= '0' and @c <= '9' or @c = '.' continue
        if @c = ' ' and @lastWasSpace = 1 continue
        set @lastWasSpace = 0
        if @c = ' ' set @lastWasSpace = 1
        set @out = @out + @c
    end
    return rtrim(@out)
end
```

This will remove all digits, periods, and duplicate spaces. You can call it like so:

```
select dbo.fFuncName('Adobe Acrobat 9.0 Pro')
```

with a result of `Adobe Acrobat Pro`.

If you need to extract the version number you could write a function that does the opposite -- keeps only the digits and periods.

Furthermore, since you're using SQL Server 2005 you have the ability to use CLR assemblies. This is only really worth it if you're processing thousands of records on a regular basis. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if it applies.

Note that neither solution will work if you don't have sufficient permissions -- if you're at a company large enough to separate out their report writers and DBAs in a policy-driven manner you likely can't create user defined functions, in which case your problem becomes quite a lot more involved without the help of your DBA.